# ReactJs - Validating proptypes

Tags: reactjs, validation, properties, react-proptypes

I have the following prop

```
this.props.history.push('/');
```

Which throws an error when trying to validate

```
AddPerson.propTypes = {
  history: React.PropTypes.Object,
}
```

My declarations

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
```

Any idea how I can validate this property?

Edit:

So my declaration now look like

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import axios from 'axios';
```

and because history is a not required prop I used default props.

```
AddPerson.defaultProps = {
  history: PropTypes.Object,
};
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: which version of react are you using ? in recent versions you have to install `prop-types` and then import it `import PropTypes from 'prop-types';` and then you can use  `AddPerson.PropTypes`, https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types

Comment: Wouldn't that also be an array, not an object?

Comment: @Aaqib yes that was part of it was working off an older version.

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
AddPerson.propTypes = {
  history: React.PropTypes.object
}
```

instead of

```
AddPerson.propTypes = {
  history: React.PropTypes.Object //should be object
}
```

Comment: remove `isRequired` as OP hasn't specified this.

Answer (score 0):

So my declaration now look like

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import axios from 'axios';
```

and because history is a not required prop I used default props.

```
AddPerson.defaultProps = {
  history: PropTypes.Object,
};
```

Comment: Well is this an answer? If no then kindly update it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Might you could do the prop type like:
`PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.object])`